# Necesito imprimir cuál es el nombre más corto de una lista que el usuario previamente ingresó

Tags: java

¡Hola! Necesito imprimir cuál es el nombre más corto de una lista que el usuario previamente ingresó. ¿Qué puedo utilizar para conocer esto(nombre más corto)? *Programación en Java*
Sencillamente necesito comparar los nombres, por cantidad de caracteres, sé que es con un .lenght pero, no sé como realizarlo.

> Un grupo tiene N estudiantes. Se pide escribir un programa que permita
>   ingresar porcada estudiante el nombre y las cuatro notas con las que
>   es evaluada una materia y que muestre:
>
> • La nota definitiva y el nombre en mayúscula si el estudiante ganó o
>   en minúscula si perdió.
>   • La diferencia entre la mayor y menor nota
>   definitiva.
>   • La cantidad de perdedores.
>   • La cantidad de nombre que
>   empiezan por M.
>   • El nombre más corto.

Nota el nombre del programa debe ser su nombre y apellidos.

```
 */
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 public class MillerBustamante
 {

    public static void  main (String[] args)
    {
        String nom;
        int n=0;
        float nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, suma=0, def=0,perdido=0,mayor=n,menor=n,contM=0,dif,contnombres=0;
            n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el numero de estudiantes a procesar "))  ;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                nom=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante " + i);
                nota1=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota número 1 del estudiante " + i));
                nota2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota número 2 del estudiante " + i));
                nota3=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota número 3 del estudiante " + i));
                nota4=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nota número 4 del estudiante " + i));
                suma= nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4;
                def=suma/4;
                if (def>=3)
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nom.toUpperCase() +" es igual a  " + def);
                }
                else 
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La nota definitiva de " + nom.toLowerCase() +" es igual a  " + def);
                }
                if (def<3)
           {           
            perdido=perdido+1;

           }
                if (nom.startsWith("M"))
            {
                contM=contM+ 1;
            }



            }
                if (def>mayor)
                    { mayor=def;


                    }
                if (def<menor)
                    {menor=def;
                    }
            dif=mayor-menor;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La diferencia entre la nota  mayor y la nota menor es: " + dif);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La cantidad de personas que perdieron son: " + perdido);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cantidad de nombres que empiezan en 'M' equivalen a: " + contM + " nombres ");



    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que deberías recorrer la lista con cualquier función para recorrer e ir mirando la longitud de ese valor. Lo almacenas en una variable y la comparas con la longitud del siguiente valor. Si es más pequeño lo almacenas, si no, pasas al siguiente.

```
guardado = lista[0];

for (x=0;x<longitud.lista;x++){
   nombre = lista[x];
   if(nombre.longitud < guardado){
      guardado = nombre;
   }
}

imprimir guardado;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el nombre mas corto, debes declarar una variable string fuera del `for` y poner la siguiente instrucción dentro del `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` :

```
String nombreCorto = "";
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{

    **Código**

    if ( nombreCorto != "" ) //Si nombreCorto es diferente a "" (declaración) comprobamos
    {
       if (nombreCorto.length() > nom.lenght()) //Si el tamaño de nombreCorto es mas grande que el de nom, asignamos nom a nombreCorto
       {
           nombreCorto = nom;
       }
    }
    else //Si no es diferente a la declaración, asignamos nom a nombreCorto
    {
       nombreCorto = nom;
    }

    ** Código **

}
```

Prueba con esto.